# Creating multiple copies of list elements

Tags: python

I have a sequence of elements, each associated with its weight `w` (a positive integer) in a tuple. What's a good way (preferably iterator-based) to create a sequence or list containing `w_i` instances of each element `e_i`?

```
weighted = [ ("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("c", 4) ]

unrolled = [ "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c" ]
```

Comment: I can spare the points, but I'm curious what the downvoters think is wrong with this question. It's got some nice answers already.

Comment: I didn't vote, but you didn't show any attempts at solving your problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension with a nested loop:

```
unrolled = [c for c, count in weighted for _ in range(count)]
```

If you are using Python 2 you could use `xrange()` instead.

If you like `itertools`, you can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to make this into a lazy iterable:

```
from itertools import chain

chain.from_iterable([c] * count for c, count in weighted)
```

Demo:

```
>>> weighted = [ ("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("c", 4) ]
>>> [c for c, count in weighted for _ in range(count)]
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([c] * count for c, count in weighted))
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

I used `list()` to turn the `chain` iterator back into a sequence.

Comment: Huh, hadn't known about the obligatory wait before answering. Nice addition, though I wonder if first-time users might wander off forever before the 15 minutes are over...

Answer (score 1):

`Counter` has this logic built in, assuming the order isn't important

```
>>> weighted = [ ("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("c", 4) ]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(dict(weighted))
>>> list(c.elements())
['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'b']
```

Another way with itertools (lots of them)

```
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat, starmap
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, weighted)))
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Comment: Nice! Indeed, order is not important. (The `Counter` solution I mean. `itertools` is just too much plumbing, when there are simpler solutions).

Comment: @alexis, I agree. I just put it there because I never get to use `starmap` anywhere

Comment: I like the `Counter` approach but I decided to accept the comprehension one because it relies on better-known features of python.

Answer (score 0):

This method basically creates a single string using a generator expression and `join`, then turns that string into a `list`.

```
weighted = [ ("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("c", 4) ]
unrolled = list(''.join([letter*count for letter,count in weighted]))

>>> unrolled
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Comment: Sorry but this strikes me as hugely circuitous, and limited to (1) strings of (2) one letter. With so much to choose from, why string multiplication?

Comment: Strings just happened to fit the use case. There is an analog for any sequence, however, for example [3]*3 is [3,3,3], so again you can use multiplication of sequences in this fashion. In that case instead of `join` you just use `chain.from_iterable`.